# How to find the number of subsets with a given length and XOR?

Tags: binary, binary-operations, dynamic-programming

I have A `(0<A<500000)` elements `(up to 10^6)` in the set. I need to find in how many ways can I remove a subset, the size of which is a multiple of a given K `(0<k<11)` - K, 2K, 3K, etc. So that the XOR of what remains is 0.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You will frequently get better feedback from other users if you share your thoughts on the problem and what you have already attempted.

Comment: I have attempted the brute-force attempt but I'm sure there is a mathematical way to go below O(n^2).